# Facebook Email Messages - How to Retrieve with API

Tags: facebook, api

If someone sends me a note using the facebook email feature (myname@facebook.com), how do you get this message using the API?  Is it possible?  I can see it in my Private Messages, but it doesn't seem to be coming over when I use FQL to query that table.  Is it possible to get these messages?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? Feel free to post the FQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request the `read_mailbox` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) from the user.  With this permission you will be able to access the messages in the users inbox.
You can read more about facebook permissions [at this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: The question was specific about how to do this with FQL. Any ideas?

Comment: @ow3 - have you taken a look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/mailbox_folder/)?

Comment: @ow3 - The OP *tried* to achieve this via FQL but the question was how to gain access to this information through their API.

Comment: You know, I think the original question is just vague enough you could interpret it both ways. The poster is trying with FQL, therefore they need to use FQL to answer the question. They don't say they are getting the permission denied error, but that doesn't mean it's not the problem. Your answer could then be correct. Would vote you up but it says I can't unless you edit.

Comment: FYI: The FQL documentation on inbox messages stinks. It doesn't make it clear how to access messages unless you already have message_id or folder_id.

Comment: @ow3 - No doubt that their documentation isn't completely adequate... It does say however that the inbox is `folder_id` 0. I guess that's a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Graph API to do this:

```
$data = $facebook->api('/me/inbox');
```

Check out: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Finbox